# React-Quill: How can I prevent the quillJS format from automatically being applied when new characters are typed?

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, quill, react-quill

I am loading an html string that represents the editor contents from my database. I want to underline/bold specific words in that string:

ex. one two **three** four five

I've figured out how to apply formatting to these specific words using [formatText](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formattext) like below:

```
editor.formatText(index, length, "bold",  'api');
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the applied format from continuing if the cursor is at the end of the formatted word

ex. one two **threeeeee** four five <- I want to avoid this

Is there a way to implement this? I can't seem to find much related to this and I am not sure implementing a custom Blot would be the right approach